# ASP.NET Button Click is not working on first click when Textbox AutoPostBack is True

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick, autopostback

I have three textbox and one button. Here is my problem:

I use `autopostback="true"` in textbox, i entered some value and after first click of the button is not working. Then i click again, second click is working. I looked on F12 developer tool on Browser, there is no an error. When i set `autopostback="false"` than button click is working without any problem.

I would like to use `autopostback="true"` because it helps me. I think there is a focus problem because when i click out of textbox and than click on the button, button works with `autopostback="true"`

Do you have any idea for solution of this problem. All controls are working server-side.

```
<asp:Textbox ID="Name" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myval" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:Textbox ID="Surname" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myval" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:Textbox ID="City" runat="server" ValidationGroup="myval" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:Button ID="send_btn" runat="server Text="Check and Send" OnClick="send_btn_Click" ValidationGroup="myval"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: That's because the TextChanged handler is firing as soon as focus leaves the textbox; setting AutoPostBack to true wires up some client script to call __doPostback when the textbox loses focus. This makes it *look like* the button (or whatever other control) handler is not working. When you say "Autopostback=true helps me" I take it you do actually have a server-side implementation for the textbox's TextChanged event ?

Comment: There is no TextChanged event on textboxes as you see. They have validation group and i set AutoPosBack="true", it's automatically checking textbox's text using validation after you click to the another textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's not stable solution but however it's working. I hope it helps you too. My solution is:

```
<asp:Button ID="send_btn" runat="server Text="Check and Send" OnClick="send_btn_Click" OnClientClick="return true;" ValidationGroup="myval"></asp:Button>
```

I added `OnClientClick="return true;"` and button click is working on first click now.

If you have better solution waiting for your response.